# How to efficiently return vector.data() pointer from a function

Tags: c++, class, vector

Please refer the code

```
class vec {

public: // Want a function here

private:
std::vector<int> abc;

};
```

I want a public member function, which efficiently returns vector pointer [using abc.data() or any other method will do]. How can I write the function?

Comment: `int* getData() { return abc.data(); }`?

Comment: You might consider why you want to do this. The caller of that function will have no idea how large the returned array is unless you also provide a function to return that information. Better to return a reference to the vector itself or a const reference if you don't want it to be modified. That reference would also still work if the vector was forced to allocate more memory in a different location.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I would suggest against returning a reference or worse, a pointer, from within a class. The reference could point to something which is out of scope. You can never know, when using it, if it is still in scope. What ever you do, consider using member functions to manipulate the vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int * func const {return abc.data();}
```

Comment: No explanation and you should explain, why this is very very bad idea